# Creating a DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a page with a table which list many results. I would like to introduce multiple dropdownlist to filter the results.

I would like to know if it could be better to create the List of SelectedItems from code behind and pass it through the viewModel or create the DropDownList directly on the Razor page?

The DropDownList will never change on this page.

Comment: Do whatever the rest of your code base is doing. Be consistent. Personally.. I would elect to make all of your model building be nowhere near the view. A view is for presenting data.. not creating it.

Comment: If you know that the values will never change at all... I'd simply hardcode them in the view.

Comment: Interesting... In my case, I use a Lmodels.ToPagedList(pageNbr, objectNbrPerPage) in my view. If I should make it on code Behind, I'll might have a problem to insert a List<SelectedItems> in my models maybe?

Comment: An issue you will hit is *whether you want each dropdown list to have the same or a different current selection*. If you need separate current selections, you would be better off passing the list of items and create the `SelectList` in the view. If they all share the same current selection, consider using a base class for all your controllers that provides the same `SelectList` in the `ViewBag` for any view.

Comment: @Robert: 1) If you think something will never change, it will. Even with U.S. States, Puerto Rico may end up being added one day. 2) Hardcoding is evil, all the time, always, no exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Note that You can have many solutions but it is better for the separation of concern to code inside the controller. So you can put your list (for the dropdown) in a `ViewBag` object and then in the View you just create a dropdown with this `ViewBag` as SelectList. For more flexibility and respect of MVC pattern the view is just used to display data from the controller.

Here just an example:

In your Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
 ....
 ViewBag.MyDropDownList1 = context.someTables.Select(t=>t);
}
```

And in your View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Somefields, ViewBag.MyDropDownList1 as SelectList,"Make the choice" )
```

Comment: does the ViewBag works through multiple pages after being initialized, I mean after creating "ViewBag.ddl = ...", could I use it on different pages ? However it seems to resolve my problem, thanks :)

Comment: ViewBag is only accessible in current view. If you want data across Views use TempData.

Comment: @malkam: `TempData` does not persist across requests either. It just persists into the *next* request, while `ViewBag` only persists in the *current* request. Regardless, it's wholly inappropriate for something like a select list, anyways.